# Video: Woman pulled from in front of a subway train. Fake or not?

Tags: video-editor

I have found a video allegedly filmed on Wednesday, Feb. 10, 2021,  at 15:35 PM, EET, in Bucharest, Ro, Dristor 1 subway station, showing a woman jumping on the tracks and then pulled out from in front of the train just less than 1 second before impact.

This is the video:
[image]
See:

The scene seems a fake but I do not know how to demonstrate it.

Comment: No signs to be fake.

Answer (score 1):

It is very difficult to say, because quality is quite bad. It is pretty obvious that it was an interlased video that was then converted to be progressive. That is why you have many ghostly images appearing during the fast motion of the object.

I do not know if this is 'fake' or 'true'. The only strange thing which i have managed to spot came at the frames 315-318 of the video.[image]

I was looking at the reflections, because they are often difficult to fake correctly. At at this moment we see the reflection coming from the part of the train with no window. In other frames during the metal part the reflection would disappear, but here it is visible, and is a little too perfect to be expected.

Now, it is possible that we are seeing the ghost of the previous/next frame due to deinterlasing, but then why does this reflection appear on several frames?

This is not something conclusive, but it did raise 32% of one of my eye brows.